# RAID 0 array REALLY slow after replacing drive

Tags: windows-10, ssd, raid, speed

I had a 3X SSD RAID 0 array (It's for a render machine so the increased failure risk is acceptable) with 2X sandisk SSDs all was working fine. I set up the RAID, installed windows 10, then did some speed tests. I then added a drive from Kingston and redid the setup - again, all good but the write speeds were lower because the Kingston drive had really low write speeds.

SO, I replaced the kingston for another sandisk SSD and followed the same method. This time instaling windows 10 took a number of hours and just crashed at the end. I assumed this could be a initialising issue (Even thogh the Intel RAID setup utility said they were ok.I reset the raid, gave it an hour or two to set, then installed windows. slow process again but got there in the end. Now it seems to hang a lot. it'll work just fine then just hang for no reason! I just did a disk speed test and it gave me 1482 MBps Seq Q32T1 Read and 1450 MBps Seq Read VS 3.197 MBps  Seq Q32T1 Write and 95.22 Seq Write :/. It also took FOREVER to run the disk check. Am I just being impatient here and it actually needs longer to initialise the RAID 0? also, if this is the case, have I done the right thing putting the OS on or do I need to start from scratch? I've also swapped out the PSU and removed the DVD drive just incase it's a pwoer issue but no luck.

It's an intel i7 with 12GB RAM

Comment: The SSD may be faulty...

Comment: How certain are you as I'll need to format the drive to test it, which sends me back to square 1. Does RAID 0 require optimise time?

Comment: If your raid monitor says that it's still building/optimising then it may be worth waiting but you've already seen better performance with a different disk with less build/optimise time than you'd think would be needed for your current setup. It's just a suggestion that you've seen better performance prior to this new disk so it may be faulty.

Comment: just removed the third drive and fired it up as a secondary drive in a different machine. fired up fine and got some decent speed test results out of it. Also used a drive health checking tool and it said healthy :/ starting to think it's not the drive.

Comment: Try different port on the raid/motherboard? Perhaps the motherboard has some 6Gbps and some 3Gbps?

Comment: It's an ASROCK H97M Pro4 - specifically purchased for it's 6X SATA 6GB/s ports :/ I tried using a different port and a different sata cable to no avail.

Comment: It would appear the drive was in fact faulty - good call mate